# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in

Tags: php, string, class

I' making this class to catch twitter posts but
I get the error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/classTest/Twitter.php on line 29
```

I cant find what's wrong...any ideas?

```
class TwitterGrub{


function twitterCapture($user = 'myUsername',$password = 'myPass') {  


           $ch = curl_init("https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml");  
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);  
           curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);  
           curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,$user . ":" . $password);  
           curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);  
           curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);  
           curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
           $result=curl_exec ($ch);  
           $data = strstr($result, '<?');  

           $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);  

      return $xml;  

}  


function twitterDisplay($twitNum){
    $xml = this->twitterCapture(); 


    for($i= 0; $i<$twitNum; $i++){ 
    echo   "<div class='curvebox'>".$xml->status[$i]->text."</div>";

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Line 29 is: echo   "<div class='curvebox'>".$xml->status[$i]->text."</div>";

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. If I past your code to codepad.org (and fix `this` to `$this`) then it gets parsed without any error. Is it the correct file?

Comment: r u sure?
I just did the same thing and I get an error on line 29...
it is really strange...

Comment: here is the link:
http://codepad.org/2yEKH4K4

Comment: you didn't put the opening php tag on that codepad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason I can find that you get the error you are getting is that you are not enclosing the code in php tags.  Paste the following code into codepad, and you will get a different error (I have made no other changes to your code):

```
<?php
class TwitterGrub{


function twitterCapture($user = 'myUsername',$password = 'myPass') {  


           $ch = curl_init("https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml");  
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);  
           curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);  
           curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,$user . ":" . $password);  
           curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);  
           curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);  
           curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
           $result=curl_exec ($ch);  
           $data = strstr($result, '<?');  

           $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);  

      return $xml;  

}  


function twitterDisplay($twitNum){
    $xml = this->twitterCapture(); 


    for($i= 0; $i<$twitNum; $i++){ 
    //echo   "<div class='curvebox'>".$xml->status[$i]->text."</div>";

    }
}

}
?>
```

Then make the change from this

```
$xml = this->twitterCapture();
```

to

```
$xml = $this->twitterCapture();
```

and the errors will magically disappear.

Answer (score 4):

```
$xml = this->twitterCapture();
```

should be

```
$xml = $this->twitterCapture();
```

Comment: thanks fro the tip... but it doesn't seem to solve the problem,
I still get the same error

Comment: Line 29 is: echo "<div class='curvebox'>".$xml->status[$i]->text."</div>";